# Android Emulator - Having the keyboard display touch input when using physical keyboard to type?

Tags: android, keyboard, emulation

was wondering if it was possible to use my physical keyboard to type, and have the android emulator simulate it as if it were a touch (specifically- the button highlights, and letter overlay)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that that will be possible.

Why do you need this?
Remember that you shouldn't base your application on that a specific input method exist if you don't want to maintain your applications for all different phones in the world. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I needed the visual feedback on the emulator for a non-programming related project for which i need video of the UI performing different tasks. Therefor typing with the mouse was a little too slow. 
I ended up writing a small osx application that you can feed a string and it will click the letters on the screen at realtime "thumb" speed. Thank you! Great community here, i'll surely be back